# Is this transcription correct?

Tags: numbers

I have found that numerals are written separately from a million. So is this transcription correct then:

> 56.353.829.543 in Worten:
>
> sechsundfunfzig milliarden dreihundertdreiundfunfzig millionen achthundertneunundzwanzigtausendfunfhundetdreinundvierzig

?

Comment: Apart from your capitalization ("Millionen" and "Milliarden" should be uppercase) and a small typo ("fünfhundertdreiundvierzig" at the end), yes.

Comment: Subject to the points made in other answers, yes it's correct, but that doesn't mean it's the only correct way of writing it. Just as in English, publishers may have their own house-styles -- which may well say that a number this big should never be written as words under any circumstances. Note also that to avoid confusion, things like phone numbers are generally spelled out as individual digits, so fünf-sechs rather than sechsundfünfzig.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Basically yes.

Small corrections:

- capitalization: it's Milliarden and Millionen
- Umlauts: it's *fünf*, not *funf*. If you can't use umlauts for some reason, it's *fuenf*, but never *funf*.
- typos on "fünfhunde**r**tdrei<s>n</s>undvierzig"

Comment: Thanks. So all umlauts, could be written with *+u? than ue, oe, ee?

Comment: @Juandev: ä can be written as ae, ö as oe, ü as ue, ß as ss. That's all we have in German.